# NSum complaining of being non-numerical

Tags: numerics, warning-messages, summation, numerical-value, convergence

I am trying to evaluate the sum $\sum_{k,l=1}^{30}\frac{1}{(k^2+l^2+1)^{5/4}}$ so I write

```
NSum[1/(1 + k^2 + l^2)^(5/4), {k, 1, 30}, {l, 1, 30}]
```

but I get a message "Summand (or its derivative) -(2.5 k (1. +k^2+l^2)^(1/4))/((1. 
+k^2+l^2)^1.25)^2 is not numerical at point l = 1."

Why is this? Everything is numerical and the sum must converge (indeed I expect the corresponding infinite sum to converge, which is ultimately what I want to evaluate), so it should be able to evaluate the sum without any warnings. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [double sum in NSum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128776/double-sum-in-nsum)

Comment: Also, if you replace all the numbers by their numeric counterparts (i.e. `1` -> `1.`) it evaluates to `1.65872`

Comment: Wrapping Sum with N, ie N[Sum[...]] does not give an error and seems to be much faster.

Comment: ^ `N[Sum[...]]` does symbolic first then converts to with `N`. If you want it even faster: `Sum[N[1/(1 + k^2 + l^2)^(5/4)], {k, 1, 30}, {l, 1, 30}, Method -> "Procedural"]`

Comment: If `30` is meant as a proxy for `Infinity`, it is not a good one.  Use `NSum[N[1/(1 + k^2 + l^2)^(5/4)], {k, 1, Infinity}, {l, 1, Infinity}]` instead.

Comment: By the way, this warning message looks like a bug to me.  What do others think?